# Empty div is hidden without any content, how to display it but keep it empty?

Tags: html, css, css-position, center

So I understand when you set a pixel width and height you can fix this problem of an empty div being hidden, but what about when using width and heights as a percentage?

Here is my code see if you can figure out how to make this div display the background color, but keep it empty... Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    opacity:0.6; filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mention class attribute in div to refer container style class

```
<div id="container"></div>

<style>
    <!--
    #container{
        position: relative;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
        background-color: #E9E9E9;
        opacity:0.6; filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    }
    -->
    </style>
```

check the demo file here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udaykiran/sbVTH/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#container:before {
    content:"\00a0\00a0"; 
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/laser_apple/JnHWy/)

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

- insert a `&nbsp;` inside the div: `<div id="container">&nbsp;</div>`
- insert `min-width:1px;` in the CSS

The height is not possible to make bigger without specifing a height number (if the DIV id empty). You can only use height percentage (`%`) if the parent has a height defined.